# Errors with itext7

Tags: java, itext7

I am trying to add some "multiple rows and columns"'s cell to table, but got
 IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("D:\\test.pdf");
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Table table = new Table(10);
    table.setWidthPercent(100);
    table.addCell(new Cell(1, 3).add(new Paragraph(1 + "_" + 3 + "_")));
    table.addCell(new Cell(1, 7).add(new Paragraph(1 + "_" + 4 + "_")));
    table.addCell(new Cell(6, 1).add(new Paragraph(6 + "_" + 1 + "_")));
    table.addCell(new Cell(6, 9).add(new Paragraph(6 + "_" + 9 + "_")));
    table.flushContent();
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.drawVerticalBorder(TableRenderer.java:1718)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.drawBorders(TableRenderer.java:1619)    
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.drawChildren(TableRenderer.java:1265)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.draw(AbstractRenderer.java:437)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.draw(TableRenderer.java:1175)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.DocumentRenderer.flushSingleRenderer(DocumentRenderer.java:118)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.processRenderer(RootRenderer.java:287)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.updateCurrentAreaAndProcessRenderer(RootRenderer.java:300)
at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:201)
at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:108)
at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:143)
```

Comment: show your full code please

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Which version of iText 7 exactly do you use? There have been bugs related to table borders in the first versions, and then the table code has been overhauled.

Comment: Version iText 7 Community 7.0.2

Comment: The exception does not appear anymore with 7.0.3-SNAPSHOT, but there is an incorrect border drawn in the first row. Thank you for letting know about the bug, it is logged into the internal bug tracking system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been fixed in `7.0.3-SNAPSHOT`. The snapshot with the fix can be downloaded from [Artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/snapshot/com/itextpdf).

The resultant file now looks like this:[image]